# IBM DB2 recreate index on truncated table

Tags: db2, reindex

After truncating table, and inserting new values in table, auto-increment values are not set to started value 1. When inserting new values it's remember last index-ed value of auto-increment.

### Colum in table named: `ID`

Index: `PRIMARY`,

Initial Value:  `1`

Cache size: `1`

Increment: `1`

[*checked on IBM DB2 Control Center*]

**This query:**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE ".$this->_schema.$table." DROP STORAGE IGNORE DELETE TRIGGERS IMMEDIATE
```

table is EMPTY.

After INSERT NEW VALUES example: `INSERT INTO DB2INST1.db (val) VALUES ('abc')` it's INSERT with LAST

```
ID | val

55 | abc
```

But it SHOULD BE:

```
ID | val

1  | abc
```

Comment: Is this a question?  This is the expected behavior for TRUNCATE TABLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here that your question is "how do you restart the `IDENTITY` sequence?"  If that is the case, then you can reset it with the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> ALTER COLUMN <IDENTITY column> RESTART WITH 1
```

However, like @Ian said, what you are seeing is the expected behavior of a `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: Yes, but I wan't detect with DESCRIBE TABLE for searching Increment column and select as <IDENTITY column>. Mean, automatically search for name of IDENTITY COLUMN, but DESCRIBE TABLE not find for increment column name.

Comment: Shortly, want find a name of <IDENTITY column> via searching of name Increment column and than put this name of column into <IDENTITY Increment>

Comment: It's not my question, I don't accept the answer. You have to wait so many days before you can accept your own answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

First select in TABLE SCHEMA WHERE is name of IDENTITY column:

Query 1:

> SELECT COLNAME FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'DB2INST1' AND
>   TABNAME = 'DB' AND IDENTITY = 'Y'

Then, truncate table and return it's example: **ID** for altering index:

Query 2:

This **ID** puts on query for reset and altering index identity:

```
ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.DB ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 1
```

Change ID above returned from Query 1, which returns name of ID to Query 2.

SOLVED!